# Loading Street View House Numbers Dataset in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to work with the [Street View House Numbers Dataset](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/) in Python. To load the .mat file digitStruct.mat in python I am using H5py

```
import h5py
labels_file = './sv/train/digitStruct.mat'
f = h5py.File(labels_file)
struct= f.values()
names = struct[1].values()
print(names[1][1].value)
```

I get `[<HDF5 object reference>]` but I need to know the actual string

Comment: check this https://github.com/hangyao/street_view_house_numbers

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `<HDF5 object reference>`, and you want to know the real data, here is one approach:

```
import h5py
labels_file = './sv/train/digitStruct.mat'
f = h5py.File(labels_file)
ref = f.get('/digitStruct/name').value[0][0]  # <HDF5 object reference>
print(f[ref].value)
```

In my environment, `f[ref].value` shows:

```
In [84]: f[ref].value
Out[84]: 
array([[ 49],
       [ 46],
       [112],
       [110],
       [103]], dtype=uint16)
```

For more information on object references, you can refer to http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/refs.html

Comment: What do those numbers represent?  I got a similar result, but was expecting to see strings rather than an array of numbers.  How does one decode the string values?

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked the dataset but this is what I suggest. 
Have a look at [this](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#Group.get) method - *get* to extract.

Apart from this, I also suggest checking [Matlab engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html) for python.

```
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
data = eng.load(labels_file,nargout=1)
```